# Text to speech using shell script

Tags: text-to-speech

I am developing an application which requires 750-1000 audio files for validating the text that is being there in the audio. I am stuck in getting the audio files for testing. Is there any script or logic where can i get audio files of simple text
For Eg:
Hi how are you?
How old are you?
Which city are you from?

Comment: I don't get it! do you simply want to search some file according to their names?

Comment: I have developed an application which will recognize the audio. I want to validate its success rate. For that i want some 500-1k audio files to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like 'festival'.
first install it:

```
apt-get install festival #in debian based distro
```

and use it like this:

- create a file with a string in it:

  cat > hello << EOF

  hello

  EOF
- run following command for making wave file:

  text2wave "hello" > hello.wav
- you can make a simple script shell to make all files you want.